# React Tabulator select in headerFilter

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

I am having an issue with react-tabulator 4.8.  I have the following field defintion:

```
{ field: 'location', title: 'Location', headerFilter: 'select', headerfilterParams: { 'here':'Here', 'there':'There' } }
```

Rather than getting a true HTML `<select />` element I get a `<input type="search" />` element.  It appears to work *mostly* the same, but it lacks the down-caret on the right as a visual indicator that it is, in fact, a select and not a free-text input.  Is there some trick to forcing the use of the `<select />` element?